# How to add claims during user registration

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity-2

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 5 project with identity 2.1.0 and VS2013 U4. I want to add claims to user during registration in order to be stored in db. These claims represent user custom properties.
As I created a web page for administrator to create/edit/delete users, I'm still using create method from `AccountController` to create a user, but I don't want to login that user. How can I add those claims to the user ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You probably already have a `UserManager` class. You can use that one to create users and to add claims.

As an example in a controller:

```
// gather some context stuff
var context = this.Request.GetContext();

// gather the user manager
var usermanager = context.Get<ApplicationUserManager>();

// add a country claim (given you have the userId)
usermanager.AddClaim("userid", new Claim(ClaimTypes.Country, "Germany"));
```

In order for this to work you need to implement your own `UserManager` and link it with the OWIN context (in the example it's `ApplicationUserManager` which basically is `class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser> { }` with only a small amount of configuration added). A bit of reading is available here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn613290%28v=vs.108%29.aspx

Comment: I succeded with this. One more question, can I change claim later in db, when user attribute changes ? And how can I access those claims in app ?

Comment: You should be able to get to those details by using navigation properties on the ApplicationUser entity (user.Claims). There's some interesting reading about that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22105583/why-is-asp-net-identity-identitydbcontext-a-black-box

Comment: O.K. I succeded to get claim, but how can I change it ?

Comment: There's no method to "modify" existing claims in `UserManager`. That route you would have to RemoveClaim() and then AddClaim(). Otherwise you could go there by the DBContext... either way you'll have to sign-out and sign-in the user again in order to get the cookie refreshed (claims are serialized in there to not hit the DB on each call for such "basic" information)

Comment: So, when some attribute is changed, I need to remove all claims and then again to add claims and to logout user ?

Comment: Not all the claims. Just that one that changed. Subsequently you'll need to log the user out and in (in that order) to have ASP.NET Identity re-serialize the (updated) claims to the session cookie

Comment: If the claims change occurs within the user's context, you can use `owinContext.Authentication.SignOut(this.User)`, otherwise you must rely on the session being re-generated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26573367/asp-identity-2-0-regenerate-identity

Comment: No, claims is not changes in user context. It is changed by another user (administrator), so I need to logout that user to apply those claims.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25878218/asp-net-identity-2-0-sign-out-another-user

Answer (score 9):

you can use Like

```
private void SignInAsync(User User)
{
    var claims = new List<Claim>();

    claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, User.Employee.Name));
    claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, User.Employee.EmailId));
    claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, User.RoleId.ToString()));
    var id = new ClaimsIdentity(claims,
                                DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
    var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(id);
    // Set current principal
    Thread.CurrentPrincipal = claimsPrincipal;
    var ctx = Request.GetOwinContext();
    var authenticationManager = ctx.Authentication;

    authenticationManager.SignIn(id);
}
```

after login pass the User table value in this function

```
 SignInAsync(result);
```

you can get clam value like

```
var identity = (ClaimsPrincipal)Thread.CurrentPrincipal;
 // Get the claims values
        string UserRoleValue = identity.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Role)
                           .Select(c => c.Value).SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: This adds the claims to the users authentication cookie and does **not** store them in the DB to be loaded on the next log-in. Also working with threads like `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` is not a good idea as threads can switch, especially in an async scenario.

Comment: @MANISH O.K. Thanks. But how can I get that user in my /Account/Login method ?

Comment: @ChrFin how can I add those to db ?

Comment: Your example won't persist the claims to DB. So the claims will only last until the session is closed, so not really what the question was about

Comment: hey you can get it by using User.Identity.GetUserName();

Answer (score 2):

You can, in fact, create claims at the same time you create the user account.

Just add the claims to the user object before you call CreateAsync on the user manager.

```
var identityUser = new IdentityUser
{
  UserName = username,
  Email = email,
  // etc...
  Claims = { new IdentityUserClaim { ClaimType = "SomeClaimType", ClaimValue = "SomeClaimValue"} }
};
var identityResult = await _userManager.CreateAsync(identityUser, password);
```

This will create the user and associate the claims with the user as one logical operation with persistence.