# Extending c# asp.net class to perform action on login

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I created a project based on the Microsoft [authorization example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?tabs=visual-studio%2Caspnetcore2x) which generated a class named ApplicationUser. I am trying to add claims to a user on account creation.

Based on [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28166739/how-to-add-claims-during-user-registration) I would add the claims to the constructor that creates the user. However that constructor doesnt seem to explicitly exist in the ApplicationUser class (but login works fine). How do I add claims to the user that has just been created?

Further, the class `ApplicationUser` doesnt have the properties `UserName` and `Email` that are being assigned to it in the Register method, which makes me think there is a lot going on in the background I'm missing.

ApplicationUser.cs

```
namespace xxx.Models
{
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
    }
}
```

AccountController.cs

```
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    public AccountController(
        UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
        SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager,
        IEmailSender emailSender,
        ILogger<AccountController> logger)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
        _emailSender = emailSender;
        _logger = logger;
    }

.........

    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
    {
        ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("User created a new account with password.");

                var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
                var callbackUrl = Url.EmailConfirmationLink(user.Id, code, Request.Scheme);
                await _emailSender.SendEmailConfirmationAsync(model.Email, callbackUrl);

                await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                _logger.LogInformation("User created a new account with password.");
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ApplicationUser doesn't have the properties UserName and Email that are being assigned to it in the Register method...

`ApplicationUser` inherits the `UserName` and `Email` properties from the `IdentityUser` class. Those properties and others are listed [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn613256(v=vs.108).aspx#Properties) in its documentation.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
}
```

> How do I add claims to the user that has just been created?

One way to add claims to a user is to use the [`UserManager.AddClaimAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1.addclaimasync?view=aspnetcore-2.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Identity_UserManager_1_AddClaimAsync__0_System_Security_Claims_Claim_) method. There is an [example of doing that here](https://github.com/aspnet/AuthSamples/blob/404105bd191f2e973d4befb668f1310d2fd82701/samples/Identity.ExternalClaims/Pages/Account/ExternalLogin.cshtml.cs#L116-L124).

In the following snippet, which is similar to your `Register` method, we add the [claim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.claims.claim?view=netframework-4.7.2) to the new user after checking that `result.Succeeded`.

```
var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
if (result.Succeeded)
{
    await _userManager.AddClaimAsync(user, new Claim("MyClaimType", "MyClaimValue"));
```