# ASP.NET Identity regenerats Identity at each request

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-identity

I have an ASP.NET MVC application and I'm using ASP.NET Identity 2. I have a weird problem. `ApplicationUser.GenerateUserIdentityAsync` is getting called for each request browser makes to my website. I've added some `Trace.WriteLine` and this is the result after removing IIS output:

```
IdentityConfig.Configuration called
ApplicationUser.GenerateUserIdentityAsync called url: http://localhost:54294/
ApplicationUser.GenerateUserIdentityAsync called url: http://localhost:54294/Content/bootstrap.css
ApplicationUser.GenerateUserIdentityAsync called url: http://localhost:54294/Scripts/modernizr-2.8.3.js
ApplicationUser.GenerateUserIdentityAsync called url: http://localhost:54294/Content/site.css
ApplicationUser.GenerateUserIdentityAsync called url: http://localhost:54294/Scripts/jquery-2.1.3.js
ApplicationUser.GenerateUserIdentityAsync called url: http://localhost:54294/Scripts/bootstrap.js
ApplicationUser.GenerateUserIdentityAsync called url: http://localhost:54294/Scripts/respond.js
ApplicationUser.GenerateUserIdentityAsync called url: http://localhost:54294/Scripts/script.js
ApplicationUser.GenerateUserIdentityAsync called url: http://localhost:54294/Glimpse.axd?n=glimpse_client&hash=8913cd7e
ApplicationUser.GenerateUserIdentityAsync called url: http://localhost:54294/Glimpse.axd?n=glimpse_metadata&hash=8913cd7e&callback=glimpse.data.initMetadata
ApplicationUser.GenerateUserIdentityAsync called url: http://localhost:54294/Glimpse.axd?n=glimpse_request&requestId=6171c2b0-b6e5-4495-b495-4fdaddbe6e8f&hash=8913cd7e&callback=glimpse.data.initData
ApplicationUser.GenerateUserIdentityAsync called url: http://localhost:54294/Glimpse.axd?n=glimpse_sprite&hash=8913cd7e
ApplicationUser.GenerateUserIdentityAsync called url: http://localhost:54294/__browserLink/requestData/38254292a54f4595ad26158540adbb6a?version=2
```

while if I run a default MVC Application created by template, I'm getting this:

```
IdentityConfig.Configuration called
```

and only if I login, It'll call `ApplicationUser.GenerateUserIdentityAsync`.

I've looked everywhere I thought it might be but I didn't find any result. I'm using (if it helps)

```
StructureMap 3
Elmah
Glimpse
ASP.NET MVC 5
EF6
ASP.NET Identity 2
```

**Additional Info**

I'm adding users directly into database without using a UserManage. I'm not sure if it makes any problems with Identity or not.

---

**Update**

I've dropped database and it didn't happen anymore. What is happening?

**Update 2**

It happened in my Google Chrome (I monitor SQL connections using glimpse) and after removing stored cookies, It didn't happen. Can logging in in other browsers cause this problem?

**Update 3**

Also log off - log in seems to solve the problem temporary.

Comment: this propbably won't help , but just a thought .  Did you try running in release mode instead of debug?  it's possible that debug mode is making a lot of extra calls

Comment: @ScottSelby funny! I've run it in the release mode and everything is fine. then I published it into my server and it happened again :|

Comment: Does ASP.NET Identity use sessions? This sounds like a case when session-ids aren't persisted between requests. If so, try setting a dummy session variable.

Comment: @SimonSvensson It seems that ASP.NET Identity doesn't use session.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem and after digging in the source code and some detective work I found a solution. The problem is inside the `SecurityStampValidator`, which is used as default `OnValidateIdentity` handler. See the source code [here](https://aspnetidentity.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin/SecurityStampValidator.cs). Interesting part:

```
var issuedUtc = context.Properties.IssuedUtc;

// Only validate if enough time has elapsed
var validate = (issuedUtc == null);
if (issuedUtc != null)
{
    var timeElapsed = currentUtc.Subtract(issuedUtc.Value);
    validate = timeElapsed > validateInterval;
}
```

This part runs for each request and if `validate` is true, then `getUserIdCallback` and `regenerateIdentityCallback` (visible in your trace output) are called. The problem here is that `issuedUtc` is always the date when cookie was created, so `validate` is always true when `validateInterval` has passed. This explains the weird behavior you were experiencing. If `validateInterval` is 10 minutes, validation logic will run for each request coming in 10 minutes and more after cookie was created (application deployed, cookies cleared, cookie reset when logging out and in again).

`SecurityStampValidator` should make the decisions whether validate or not, basing on the previous validation date (or issued date when it's a first check), but it's not doing so. To make `issuedUtc` date move forward there are 3 possible solutions:

- reset the cookie each `validateInterval`, this means `SingOut` and `SignIn`. Similar solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26579284). This seems like a costly operation, especially if `validateInterval` is set to only a couple of minutes.
- take advantage of the `CookieAuthenticationOptions.SlidingExpiration` logic to have the cookie re-issued automatically. Explained very well in [this post](http://www.jamessturtevant.com/posts/ASPNET-Identity-Cookie-Authentication-Timeouts/#expiretimespan).

> If SlidingExpiration is set to true then the cookie would be re-issued on any request half way through the ExpireTimeSpan. For example, if the user logged in and then made a second request 16 minutes later the cookie would be re-issued for another 30 minutes. If the user logged in and then made a second request 31 minutes later then the user would be prompted to log in.

In my case (intranet application) users being logged out after 30 minutes of inactivity is unacceptable. I need to have the default `ExpireTimeSpan`, which is 14 days. So the option here would be to implement some kind of ajax polling to extend the cookie life. Sounds like a lot of effort to accomplish this fairly simple scenario.

- the last option, which I finally chose to use is to modify `SecurityStampValidator` implementation to have the sliding validation approach. Example code below. Remember to replace `SecurityStampValidator` with `SlidingSecurityStampValidator` in Startup.Auth.cs. I added `IdentityValidationDates` dictionary to the original implementation to store the validation dates for each user and then I'm using it when checking if validation is needed.

  ```
  public static class SlidingSecurityStampValidator
  {
      private static readonly IDictionary<string, DateTimeOffset> IdentityValidationDates = new Dictionary<string, DateTimeOffset>();

      public static Func<CookieValidateIdentityContext, Task> OnValidateIdentity<TManager, TUser, TKey>(
          TimeSpan validateInterval, Func<TManager, TUser, Task<ClaimsIdentity>> regenerateIdentityCallback,
          Func<ClaimsIdentity, TKey> getUserIdCallback)
          where TManager : UserManager<TUser, TKey>
          where TUser : class, IUser<TKey>
          where TKey : IEquatable<TKey>
      {
          if (getUserIdCallback == null)
          {
              throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(getUserIdCallback));
          }

          return async context =>
          {
              var currentUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
              if (context.Options != null && context.Options.SystemClock != null)
              {
                  currentUtc = context.Options.SystemClock.UtcNow;
              }
              var issuedUtc = context.Properties.IssuedUtc;

              // Only validate if enough time has elapsed
              var validate = issuedUtc == null;
              if (issuedUtc != null)
              {
                  DateTimeOffset lastValidateUtc;
                  if (IdentityValidationDates.TryGetValue(context.Identity.Name, out lastValidateUtc))
                  {
                      issuedUtc = lastValidateUtc;
                  }

                  var timeElapsed = currentUtc.Subtract(issuedUtc.Value);
                  validate = timeElapsed > validateInterval;
              }

              if (validate)
              {
                  IdentityValidationDates[context.Identity.Name] = currentUtc;

                  var manager = context.OwinContext.GetUserManager<TManager>();
                  var userId = getUserIdCallback(context.Identity);
                  if (manager != null && userId != null)
                  {
                      var user = await manager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
                      var reject = true;

                      // Refresh the identity if the stamp matches, otherwise reject
                      if (user != null && manager.SupportsUserSecurityStamp)
                      {
                          var securityStamp = context.Identity.FindFirstValue(Constants.DefaultSecurityStampClaimType);
                          if (securityStamp == await manager.GetSecurityStampAsync(userId))
                          {
                              reject = false;
                              // Regenerate fresh claims if possible and resign in
                              if (regenerateIdentityCallback != null)
                              {
                                  var identity = await regenerateIdentityCallback.Invoke(manager, user);
                                  if (identity != null)
                                  {
                                      // Fix for regression where this value is not updated
                                      // Setting it to null so that it is refreshed by the cookie middleware
                                      context.Properties.IssuedUtc = null;
                                      context.Properties.ExpiresUtc = null;
                                      context.OwinContext.Authentication.SignIn(context.Properties, identity);
                                  }
                              }
                          }
                      }

                      if (reject)
                      {
                          context.RejectIdentity();
                          context.OwinContext.Authentication.SignOut(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
                      }
                  }
              }
          };
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. although I'm not working on that project anymore but your answer seems right so I make it accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible issues that are causing this the reset:

1. The cookie IssuedUtc Date is invalid (`issuedUtc` property on the cookie is `null`)
2. The identity validate interval is set incorrectly.

In your `startup.cs` class you will find the Cookie Authentication configuration.  And inside the configuration is a function delegate that should be set like the following:

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ...

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
            }
        });            

        ...
    }
}
```

Check to see that your `validateInterval` is not set to a low value.  In the case above there will be a database ( `user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync`) call 30 minutes after a valid cookie was issued.   In your case it maybe set to a low value like every second.

If you are using the logout everywhere functionality (security stamp) a change to the `validateInterval` will allow the cookie to remain valid until the `OnValidateIdentity` function is called.